# About this Wikipedia derivation of relation between samples of a function and samples of its Fourier transform.

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

The derivation below of the relation between samples of a function, $s(t)$, and samples of the Fourier transform of the same function, $\hat s(f)$, can be found in [this](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Poisson_summation_formula#/Distributional_formulation) wiki article.
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \hat s(\nu + k/T)
&= \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \mathcal{F}\left \{ s(t)\cdot e^{-i 2\pi\frac{k}{T}t}\right \}\\
&= \mathcal{F} \bigg \{s(t)\underbrace{\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-i 2\pi\frac{k}{T}t}}_{T \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(t-nT)}\bigg \}
= \mathcal{F}\left \{\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} T\cdot s(nT) \cdot \delta(t-nT)\right \}\\
&= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} T\cdot s(nT) \cdot \mathcal{F}\left \{\delta(t-nT)\right \}
= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} T\cdot s(nT) \cdot e^{-i 2\pi nT \nu}.
\end{align}$$

What is the justification behind the replacement of $s(t)$ by $s(nT)$ in the second line of this derivation?

Answer (score 1):

we know  that  multiplication by shifted delta function means sampling value of function at that instant only i.e,

$f(t)\times \delta(t-t_{0})=f(t_{0})\times\delta(t-t_{0})$ (sifting property)

now, coming to your second line

$= \mathcal{F} \bigg \{s(t)\underbrace{\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-i 2\pi\frac{k}{T}t}}_{T \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(t-nT)}\bigg \}$

$= \mathcal{F}\left \{\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} T\cdot s(t) \cdot \delta(t-nT)\right \}\\$

$
= \mathcal{F}\left \{\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} T\cdot s(nT) \cdot \delta(t-nT)\right \}\\$ (replacement of $s(t)$ by $s(nT)$ is done by using sifting property with $t_{0}=nT$ )